# Query to select person on a table that has a class name on another table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I've been at this for a while.

Basically it's a query that needs to identify:

> "In which courses do people who only drink one type of beer teach?
> (Name of course (s))"

Table 1 : The relation K contains information about courses: their course code (KKOD), course name (NAME), number of points (POINTS) and course abbreviation (NICKNAME).

Table 2: The relationship PB contains information on people's total beer consumption divided into different varieties: the person's name (NAME), Systembolaget's article number (SYSNR) and the number of liters consumed (LITER).

There's more tables but I believe only those two are needed to respond to the question.

First I wanted to write a query that identifies the people who only have drunken one type of beer.

> `select * from pb group by namn having count(*)=1;`

Then I tried to write a query combining the above query to list the courses but here's where nothing happens or if I do some variations, all of the courses will list, not just the ones I need.

```
Try 1: select namn from pb group by namn having count(*)=1 where exists(select knamn from K where pb.namn = k.knamn);

Try 2: select knamn from k where exists(select namn from pb by group by namn having count(*)=1);
```

Doesn't work, any recommendations?
Thank you

Comment: what is knamn in table K? You've not mentioned this column as a part of relation K?

Answer (score 1):

The description of the tables seem to be lacking an ability to join them. Let's just assume you have a person_id or name in both tables.

This is the question:

```
"In which courses do people who only drink one type of beer teach? (Name of course (s))"
```

You can use a CTE to first obtain the names of people who drink only one type of beer, and use in a query such as this:

```
    with beer_types as
    (
      select person_name
      from beers
      group by person_name
      having count(distinct beer_type) = 1
    )
    select c.person_name, c.course_code
    from courses c
    join beer_types bt
      on c.person_name = bt.person_name
```

DB-Fiddle found [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/boGSmLLe5QbWyLZAxxdqZr/0).